# How can I fix the issue with gradient figure rendering on Safari on devices with ARM processors?

Tags: javascript, debugging, canvas, safari, arm

Upon attempting to display a figure filled with a gradient color and rotating it, there is an issue with the display that manifests in the form of horizontal stripes. This can be seen in the attached screenshot. In addition, the code can be found in the link or in this message below.

[image]

https://codepen.io/borodin-the-sans/pen/ZEjpJaB

The problem is only displayed in Safari browsers on mobile devices or on Apple silicon processors.

```js
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body style="background-color: black">
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<script>
    const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    let rotation = 1.3;

    function draw() {
        ctx.save();

        ctx.translate(256, 256);
        ctx.rotate(rotation);

        const gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(-128, -128, 256, 256);
        gradient.addColorStop(0, 'red');
        gradient.addColorStop(1, 'blue');
        ctx.fillStyle = gradient;

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(128, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(0, 128);
        ctx.lineTo(-128, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(0, -128);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();

        ctx.restore();
    }

    canvas.width = canvas.height = 512;
    draw();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If I change the degree of rotation of the polygon or use fillRect or replace the gradient with a simpler color, the problem will disappear.

But I need to use animation of rotation in more complex gradient polygons. I do not expect to see horizontal stripes in the top of the polygon.

I can calculate the size and position of this artifact and clear it. But it will become unbearable if I use any background in canvas.

Comment: Open an issue at https://bugs.webkit.org Looks like a GPU bug, though if I'm still up to date, I believe Safari still didn't implement `willReadFrequently`, so no easy way to disable GPU rendering. One thing you could try is to `clip()` using your path before calling `fill()`, might cause some antialiasing artifacts but if it's ankmated that might not be too noticeable. Otherwise you could mask your shape using compositing and a solid fill style.

Comment: I checked with `clip()`, it gives the same result as `fill()`.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue and it really seems like a bug in Webkit. [Here is the bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=250146) on the official WebKit Bugzilla.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works in my case.
It is necessary to draw lines of a length of at least 1 pixel outside canvas so that the artifact is not noticeable.

```js
ctx.moveTo(0, -1);
ctx.lineTo(0, 0);
```

Full code:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

let rotation = 1.3;

function draw() {
  ctx.save();

  ctx.translate(256, 256);
  ctx.rotate(rotation);

  const gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(-128, -128, 256, 256);
  gradient.addColorStop(0, 'red');
  gradient.addColorStop(1, 'blue');
  ctx.fillStyle = gradient;

  ctx.beginPath();
  
  // fix bug
  ctx.moveTo(0, -1);
  ctx.lineTo(0, 0);
  
  ctx.moveTo(128, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(0, 128);
  ctx.lineTo(-128, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(0, -128);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();

  ctx.restore();
}

canvas.width = canvas.height = 512;
draw();
```

```css
body{
  background-color: black
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You may want to apply your "fix" before you do the transforms, because here your line is in the middle of the canvas, you can see it if you do stroke your path.